# rails - form_for - how to have my 'Property' form update the 'Ticket' model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

I have 3 tables- `OwnerofProperty` , `Property` and `Ticket`. I want to make a form using `form_for` to represent property booking; can I make a form to retrieve data from `Property` where the submit button saves the data in the `Ticket` table? I am asking because I have no idea if that can be possible or how to make it.

Note: I have only created the relations : 
`OwnerofProperty` one-to-many `Property`

`Property`        one-to-one  `Ticket`

I need this form just to make a user able to see the avaliable properties and can book only one , how to make this form ?

Schema.rb for the three models :

```
create_table "owners", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "f_name"
    t.string   "l_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "tel_no"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "properties", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "p_street"
    t.string   "p_city"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "property_type"
    t.integer  "rooms"
    t.integer  "rent"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

  add_index "properties", ["owner_id"], :name => "index_properties_on_owner_id"

  create_table "tickets", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "ticket_type"
    t.integer  "rooms"
    t.integer  "rent"
    t.integer  "property_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  add_index "tickets", ["property_id"], :name => "index_tickets_on_property_id"
```

Comment: Can you share some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I made the relations only and I didn't make any code in the controller or the view until now because I don't know what I want to do can be possible or not, all i can do a signup form :(

Comment: You can specify which controller and action you are POSTing the data to - just specify these in your `form_for`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: a better question name will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

let's see `ticket_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @property = Property.find 20  #20 is property id
  @properties = Property.all
  #@ticket = Ticket.new
end
```

now in `view` (where you want to create form):

```
<%= form_for @ticket do |f| %>
<%= f.select :property_id, @properties.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }%> <!-- just an example, Ticket model has a field named "property_id" -->
<%= f.submit %>
<%= end %>
```

this form submits to `create` action of `ticket_controller`. And you are able to get all data as `params` and save it to table.

```
def create
@ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
@ticket.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{redirect_to( your_desired_path)}
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn´t it be form_for @ticket do |f| instead of [@property, @ticket], and Property.all.collect instead of @properties? where do you set @properties?

Comment: hmm if the relation is one-to-one Property and Ticket your select field makes no sense I think. you should exclude all Properies which already are assigned to a ticket. But it is definitly a good example to get the basic idea.

Comment: you should nest your routes like following: :resources :properties do :resources :tickets end

Comment: undefined method for collect and please tell me how create method should look like

Comment: #new
undefined method model_name in this line <%= f.select :property_id, @properties.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }%>

Comment: is there any field `property_id` in `Ticket` model?

Comment: yes there is , but there is no data in Tickets model , because it should be filled through the form

Comment: please ensure your `Property` model has field `name`. If still getting error please provide your schema of your 3 Models.

Comment: question updated , maybe the relation should be ticket has_on property and property belongs_to ticket ???

Comment: oh, I figured it out. Your `Property` model haven't any `name` field but you are pulling here `@properties.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]`. So out something like: `<%= f.select :property_id, @properties.collect {|p| [ p.property_type, p.id ] }%>`.